# With our best employee leaving the company

Tags: grammar

Suppose that the best employee already left the company. Are the following sentences okay?

> With our best employee leaving the company, we cannot complete the project on time.

> With our best employee having left the company, we cannot complete the project on time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With our best employee leaving the company, we cannot complete the
> project on time.

"Leaving" means the employee is currently leaving and has not yet left — that they are still at the company.

People would likely understand the message this sentence sends, but this sentence does not *exactly* say what I think you are trying to say.

> With our best employee having left the company, we cannot complete the
> project on time.

This is okay; "left", as used here, is past tense, and says the employee has already left.

I would *personally* use:

> We cannot complete the project on time, since our best employee left the company.

...or...

> We can't complete the project in time, since our company's best employee left.

...if you like contractions.

Both put the thing that cannot be completed in time (the project) ahead of the reason *why* the thing cannot be completed in time (the employee leaving).

But that is just what I would do. Your 2nd sentence is "okay" as it is.

Comment: Do you also think "learning" is not OK in the following? "Even with him learning that neither parent had taken the news well, he had a more optimistic view of his future. "

Comment: @Apollyon It is "OK", and would work in a conversation, but I would use "Even after learning neither parent took the news well, he had a more optimistic view of his future." In this case, "took" means the same as "had taken". Also, the "that" in "learning that neither parent had taken the news well" is redundant, although I, myself, cannot really explain why very well. Basically, "neither parent had taken the news well", is already assumed to be a fact by itself. "Learning THAT" it happened does not work; you just "learn" it. It's like "learning a language" (just, in this case, "learned".).

Comment: My question is, why "learning" is okay in this particular example while "leaving" is not okay in the OP example. Why the difference?

Comment: @Apollyon I partially take back my earlier comment: that sentence, as a whole, does not seem grammatically correct, and I did not correctly identify why. The "with" is the actual problem; it implies him learning happened at the same time as him taking a more optimistic view, when, really, the learning happened before that. In this case, the "with" implies things happening at the same time. Another example: "eating eggs with bacon" implies the eggs and bacon were eaten at the same time, whereas "eating eggs after bacon" implies the eggs were eaten after the bacon. You need "after", not "with".

Comment: I found this interesting example, where "quitting" rather than "having quit" is used, even though the quitting already happened: "Another big reveal at the end of tonight’s episode is that Sterling K. Brown’s Randall Pearson tells his wife Beth (Watson), that he wants to adopt a kid. But, he hasn’t even told her he **quit** his job yet. “I think she’s OK with him **quitting** his job,” said Watson, “but I think her supporting him with the adoption might be an issue.” That is especially after she had the pregnancy scare earlier in the season."

Comment: @Apollyon Beth uses "quitting", not "quit", since she knows Pearson quit in the past, but saying "she's OK that he quit his job" is also OK. "OK that he quit his job" refers to past events as ones that already happened. "OK with him quitting his job" is different: it "remembers" when Pearson was *in the process of* quitting, but had *not yet* quit. "OK with him quitting his job" has a slightly different use from "OK that he quit his job": it implies Beth *was* OK with Pearson quitting at the time he was doing so, but that she is *not* OK with (or *less* OK with) something in the present.

Comment: @Apollyon English is a very strange language in many ways.